# How can I show data in the header of a multipage SSRS 2005 report?

Tags: reporting-services, header, report

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63938/how-do-i-show-data-in-the-header-of-a-sql-2005-reporting-services-report) was very helpful, however I have a list control in my report, and when the report grows over 1 page, data in the header only shows up on the last page of the report.

Apparently, hidden textboxes have to be on every page of the report for header to function properly. How do I do that? The only control I have in the list is a textbox with bunch of text that grows way over 1 page.

Comment: Is this a matter of Page Properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sExchange website to the rescue!!!

All I needed to do is to use Report Parameters with queried values from my dataset; and then reference =Parameters!Name.Value in the textbox in the header of the report.

Answer (score 6):

Although SSRS does not allow us to use DataSet fields in page headers, it allows us to refer to report items. So we could place a textbox (that takes its value from a DataSet field) anywhere in our report's body and set its `Hidden` property to true.

Then, we could easily refer to that textbox in the page header with an expression like: `=ReportItems!TextBox1.Value` and we are done. Note that the textbox that is being referred should be present on every page, or otherwise the header will print an empty value.

Answer (score 1):

Select Report Parameters, Add new parameter and check hidden, allow null and allow blank value.

If you are retrieving the values from database:

### Under Available Values:

check "from query" radio button and provide dataset,value field and label fields.

### Under Default Values:

check "from query" radio button and provide dataset,value fields.

Now provide the value for text box in the footer/header as `=Parameters!Footer.Value` (`Footer` is the parameter name).

Answer (score 0):

the hidden text boxes can be placed within a rectangle that was a repeatwith property set to be your list item.