# Using Report Parameters in Header

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, reportparameter

I've read [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63938/how-do-i-show-data-in-the-header-of-a-sql-2005-reporting-services-report) that recommend using parameters when displaying dynamic data in the header because it renders correctly in pdf.  I am trying to implement that solution but have run into an issue.  It works when data is returned for a parameter, but it throws an error if data is not returned.  Here is my setup:

- Hidden
- Allow null value
- Allow blank value
- Available values: From query
- Default values: From query

The textbox in my header has the following value:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Parameters![Report Parameter Name].Value), "", Parameters![Report Parameter Name].Value)
```

When a row is not returned for the default value, it displays the error:

> The '[Report Parameter Name]' parameter is missing a value.

I'm new to reporting services so I may be missing some large concept.  To me, no data returned fits the **Allow null value** criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using IIF in cases with IsNothing and also in similar divide by zero cases is that it is not a language construct, it is actually a function. Therefore, the parameters are evaluated before calling the function, which means that the expression that you think shouldn't be evaluated IS actually evaluated before the function call.

I know it seems crazy that both the true and false parts of an IF expression are calculated but think of it as a function call and not a language feature. There is no path short circuiting like in a language, the error is in the calculation of ALL the parameters prior to calling the function.

You can replace this with a custom code function to do the same effect that you are after. So something along the following lines:

Right-click the body of the report and choose Properties. Click the Code tab and enter the following code:

```
Public Function GetParamVal(ByVal ParamVal) As String
    If IsNothing(ParamVal) Then
        Return ""
    Else 
        Return ParamVal
    End If
End Function
```

Then call it in your header like so:

```
=Code.GetParamVal(Parameters!MyParam.Value)
```

(I'm not in front of a system to test this on but you should get the idea)

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for that explanation.  I don't use VB so I wasn't familiar with the nuances of IsNothing and IIF.